# 'To be taken serious' or 'to be taken seriously'

Tags: idioms, adjectives, adverbs

The following sentence is from an essay written by a British who is also an former IELTS examiner.

''Global warming should be taken more serious as it can result in a number of disastrous consequences. ''

In many sources, word preference is ''seriously'' in this context. However, the writer preferred ''serious'' and I can't explain why. I read the discussion on English Stack Exchange, also read answers given to similar questions with mine on English forums and Qura but I still can't explain why the writer chose ''serious'' rather than ''seriously'' and I'm dubious whether it is a mistake or not.

Comment: Sorry, but I've never heard a thing, or a forum called "Qura".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds wrong. It should be either

*taken more seriously*
or
*taken as more serious*

Answer (score 2):

"Serious" is an adjective. "Seriously" is an adverb.

So, you can take something seriously. Or you can treat something as serious. If the word is modifying the subject, you want the adjective. If it is modifying the verb, you want the adverb.

In the sentence quoted, the adverb applies.

Compare:

> Global warming should be taken less seriously because after more than a century of warming none of the purported disastrous consequences have occurred.